# Shell script to ask user inputs from terminal to enter company name, employ name, employee ID, and employee competency and display the output on

Tags: shell

Shell script to ask user inputs from terminal to enter company name, employ name, employee ID, and employee competency and display the output on terminal.shell script to ask user to enter the ATM pin, account (savings or current), amount and finally display the output, “your transaction is successfully completed”?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read -p "company name:" company

read -p "Employee name:" ename

read -p "Employee ID:" eid

read -p "Employee company:" ec

echo

echo "company name is : $company"

echo "employee name is : $ename"

echo "employee id is : $eid"

echo "employee competency is : $ec"

echo

read -sp "Enter ATM pins:" pin

read -p "enter the account savings or current:" sav

read -p "Amount:" amount

echo "your transaction is successfully completed"